# Why is == different than === here?

Tags: javascript

Why does javascript treat `"xy" == new String("xy")` as true, but `"xy" === new String("xy")` as false?.

I have read [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators](http://Mozilla%20Expressions%20and%20Operators), but am still confused

Comment: Check `typeof "xy"` and `typeof new String("xy")` and `===` also compares the type.

Comment: === also compares the *types*, and they ain't the same, innit.

Comment: Please do not ask duplicate questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons

Answer (score 4):

```
typeof "xy"
```

is "string"

```
typeof new String("xy")
```

is "object"

`===` compares both value and type

`==` converts the types and then compares just the values

Comment: Okay. Then how this answers the question.

Comment: @Tushar sorry have ammended

Comment: _=== compares both value and type_ Can you please explain why `==` returns `true`?

Answer (score 0):

the `==` operator just compares the values, `===` compares values and types. So type of `"xy"` is `string` and type of `new String()` is object. That's why you see the difference between those two comparisons